# Convergence speed of generating sequences for potentially convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given two complex sequences $(a_n)_{n_\in\mathbb{N}},(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ that converge to zero we consider the series $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$. Assume now that the first converges and the second diverges to infinity. It feels fairly obvious (but apparently isn't at all) that
$$\frac{a_n}{b_n}\to 0 \text{ as }n\to\infty.$$
Nonetheless I have failed to prove this, probably because I am quite rusty on the basics and missing something hugely obvious. Can anyone help me out? Do I need absolute convergence of the first series?

Comment: What about $a_n=1/n^2$, $b_n=1/n^2$ for odd $n$, and $b_n=1/n$ for even $n$ (say)?

Comment: Very true, it seems like this is a counterexample. This is surprising, but at least reassuring that my failing to prove it is not necessarily a sign of my rustiness but rather because it is simply impossible.